# Recommended Vim plugins for JavaScript coding?

Tags: javascript, vim

I'm new to JS & Vim. Which plugins would help me to write Javascript code?

Comment: To give the question more clarity, and to help the OP in their English for future posts...

It should read: "Hi, I'm new to JS & Vim. Which plugins would help me to write Javascript code?"

You can say "I am new _to_ Javascript and vim". You can use "what is" for singular, so for example "What is _a_plugin_ that would help me..." or you can use "which" for plural like this: "_Which_plugins_ would help me...". Also notice that instead of "plugins _is_" you should use "plugins _would_" because it's a hypothetical.
Hope that helps :-)

Comment: @hendrixski - vote to reopen this.

Comment: Most constructive not-constructive question ever.

Comment: I quite enjoy how this "not constructive" question helped me improve a lot my workflow.

Comment: Since the question is (unfairly IMO) closed, I'll just add a comment here: there's an electron-based front-end for NeoVim with typescript language server autocompletion out of the box (works with vanilla JS too!): https://www.onivim.io/. It's still a bit rough around the edges but I've been using it as my daily driver for a few weeks now and haven't had too many issues. It has a really good community around it, and it's under _very_ heavy development, so I expect good things from it in the future! Full disclosure: I make a monthly donation to the project and plan to contribute in the future.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

### Syntax Checking / Linting

There is a very easy way to integrate JSLint or the community-driven [jshint.com](https://jshint.com/) (which is much better IMO) with Vim using the Syntastic Vim plugin. See [my other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473478/vim-jslint/5893447#5893447) for more info.

### Source-Code browsing / Tag-list

There's also a very neat way to add tag-listing using Mozilla's *DoctorJS* (formerly *jsctags*), which is also used in [Cloud9 IDE](https://web.archive.org/web/20200204181809/http://cloud9ide.com/)'s [Ace online editor](http://ace.ajax.org/).

1. Install the following packages using your favorite package-manager (Ubuntu's `apt-get`, Mac's [home `brew`](https://brew.sh/), etc.):

   1. `exuberant-ctags`

- **NOTE:** After installing make sure running `ctags` actually runs `exuberant-ctags` and not the OS's preinstalled `ctags`. You can find out by executing `ctags --version`.
  2. `node` (Node.js)

2. Clone `DoctorJS` from github: `git clone https://github.com/mozilla/doctorjs.git`
3. Go inside `DoctorJS` dir and `make install` (You'll also need the `make` app installed, but this is very basic).

- There're some bugs with installing the plugin, `make install` doesn't do the trick for the moment. For now I just add the repo's `bin/` dir to my $PATH instead. See [DoctorJS's GitHub and issues pages](https://github.com/mozilla/doctorjs) for more info.

4. Install the [TagBar Vim plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3465) (**NOTE:** It's TagBar, not the old infamous TagList!).
5. PROFIT. :)

#### New Project - Tern.js

[DoctorJS is currently dead](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/js-tools/tZ-1jDYxGZk). There's a new promising project called [tern.js](https://ternjs.net/). It's currently in early beta, and should eventually replace it.

There is a project [ramitos/jsctags](https://github.com/sergioramos/jsctags) which uses tern as its engine. Just `npm install -g` it, and tagbar will automatically use it for javascript files.

Comment: +1 for TagBar (was only aware of TagList!)

Comment: @RobM: Yeah, it's way better than the old TagList. You're welcome to join it's development at http://majutsushi.github.com/tagbar/

Comment: Currently doctorjs requires you to clone recursive as specified in [this bug](https://github.com/mozilla/doctorjs/issues/12), `git clone --recursive https://github.com/mozilla/doctorjs.git` and then make install should work

Comment: For anyone trying to use the latest DoctorJS, keep track of this ticket: [jsctags no longer reports scope of tags](https://github.com/mozilla/doctorjs/issues/5) (unresolved as of 10 Jan 2011)

Comment: doctorjs on Windows: http://baumichel.blogspot.ca/2011/11/how-to-install-doctorjsjsctags-on.html
adding additional filetypes to TagBar: https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar/wiki

Comment: Before doing step 3, cd into doctorjs and do this: `git submodule init && git submodule update`. Then do step 3.

Comment: The brew command is actually `brew install ctags-exuberant`

Comment: why **exuberant-ctags** is needed?

Comment: tag-list doesn't support prototype function

Comment: @sunglim - This is not TagList's fault - I believe it's a bug in doctorjs which creates the source tree. TagList just shows it on Vim.

Comment: @OryBand vote to reopen this question

Comment: @Slomjo how can I do that?

Comment: It looks like the tern-based solution is out: https://github.com/ramitos/jsctags

Comment: +1 for TagBar too, browses JS classes and foo()s with ease.

Comment: It doesn't support IIFE and also AMD module.

Answer (score 17):

[snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) emulates TextMate's <kbd>⇥</kbd> insertion system and comes with a bunch of useful JS snippets (among others) by default. It's extremely easy to add your own.

[javaScriptLint](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2578) allows you to validate your code against [jsl.](http://www.javascriptlint.com)

Also you can find a variety of [JavaScript syntax files](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=javascript&script_type=syntax&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search) on vim.org. Try them and see which one works best for you and your coding style.

The native omnicomplete (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>-<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>) works very well for me. You can make it more dynamic with [autoComplPop](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879), but it can be annoying sometimes.

**edit, in response to tarek11011's comment:**

acp doesn't work for JavaScript by default, you have to tweak it a little. Here is how I did it (dirty hack, I'm still a Vim noob):

In vim-autocomplpop/plugin/acp.vim I've added `php` and `javascript` (and `actionscript`) to `behavs` so that it looks like that :

```
let behavs = {
    \   '*'            : [],
    \   'ruby'         : [],
    \   'python'       : [],
    \   'perl'         : [],
    \   'xml'          : [],
    \   'html'         : [],
    \   'xhtml'        : [],
    \   'css'          : [],
    \   'javascript'   : [],
    \   'actionscript' : [],
    \   'php'          : [],
    \ }
```

A little below, there is a series of code blocks that look like that :

```
"---------------------------------------------------------------------------
call add(behavs.ruby, {
    \   'command' : "\<C-x>\<C-o>",
    \   'meets'   : 'acp#meetsForRubyOmni',
    \   'repeat'  : 0,
    \ })
```

I've duplicated this one and edited it a little bit to look like that:

```
"---------------------------------------------------------------------------
call add(behavs.javascript, {
    \   'command' : "\<C-x>\<C-o>",
    \   'meets'   : 'acp#meetsForRubyOmni',
    \   'repeat'  : 0,
    \ })
```

and did the same for actionscript and php.

If you want to edit JS/CSS within a HTML document you can do :set ft=html.css.javascript in Vim's command line to make <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>-<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> work as expected on method/properties names in JS blocks and properties/values in CSS blocks. However this approach has its drawbacks, too (weird indentation…).

Comment: How did you do those cool looking keystrokes?

Comment: Haha, it's <kbd></kbd>. Browsers usually have no default styling for this tag, kudos to the SO team for doing the extra work.

Comment: thank you romainl , but a have a problem with autoComplPop it is work only with html file no js and css and php

Comment: Like a lot of Vim plugins acp is very sensitive to filetypes. If the buffer's filetype is "html", neither acp nor omni complete will work for embedded JS/CSS/PHP. And I'm going to edit my answer, not enough editing options/room here.

Comment: You may prefer to use the [current maintenance branch of snipMate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) that Rok Garbas & co. put together.

Comment: (And by "branch" I mean "fork".)

Comment: @romainl - vote to reopen this question

Answer (score 8):

This plugin is also useful: https://github.com/maksimr/vim-jsbeautify.
It provides full autoformatting for javascript.
One keystroke, and your code looks beautiful. It can come in handy when pasting code snippets as well.
It makes use of the popular js-beautifier, which can also be found as an online application. The latter can be found right here: http://jsbeautifier.org/.

Comment: I wrote a general autoformatting plugin for vim which integrates the js-beautifier and more. Check here: https://github.com/Chiel92/vim-autoformat

Comment: prettitier - the best

Answer (score 6):

I only use one js specific vim plugin - jslint.vim - https://github.com/hallettj/jslint.vim which validates your code with jslints rules and gives you syntax errors as well.

Comment: thanks but I think I have a problem look at http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/7629/11142565.png

Comment: Hm, on windows there are specific instructions you'll need to follow, it requires a javascript interpreter.  I haven't tried installing it on windows, but the install instructions are down the page a bit in the README, sorry I can't be more help there.

Answer (score 3):

To fix indentation and autoformatting (Ctrl =): [JavaScript Indent](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3081)

To set indentation width, add `javascript.vim` file into ~/.vim/ftplugin dir with following contents (for two space indentation):

```
 setl sw=2 sts=2 et
```

Comment: in `~/.vimrc` : `autocmd FileType javascript setlocal sw=2 ts=2 sts=2`