# Vim, Javascript, DoctorJS (jsctags) and Taglist (Source code browsing)

Tags: javascript, vim, taglist, jsctags

I've installed [DoctorJS](http://doctorjs.org/) (previously *jsctags*) in an attempt to get some good source-code browsing/tag-listing for Vim (using the [Taglist](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273) plugin).

Installing went fine, but Vim's *Taglist* doesn't work with DoctorJS.

When trying to open the tag-list window in Vim via `:TListToggle`, I get the following error:

```
Taglist: Failed to generate tags for /home/me/script.js
ctags: illegal option -- -^@usage: ctags [-BFadtuwvx] [-f tagsfile] file ...^@
```

I've searched the www, and found out [this guide, suggesting a replacement plugin called *Taglist-Plus*](http://discontinuously.com/2011/03/vim-support-javascript-taglist-plus/), but it doesn't work with DoctorJS, only with the old unmaintained version, *jsctags*.

In short - I can't get this to work. Very frustrating. We should be able to have good JavaScript source-code browsing!

Any Vim wizzes out there that have managed to get this thing working?

Thanks in advance.

### Better Solution:

After resolving this problem (thanks for the answer, *@romainl*), [I wrote a short guide on how to get this thing done easily as an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777366/recommended-vim-plugins-for-javascript-coding/5893600#5893600). I recommend to check it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use [TagBar](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3465). The latest version is supposed to support DoctorJS.