# Vim Javascript Autocompletion + Suggestions?

Tags: javascript, vim, jsctags

I'm developing on top of OpenLayers.js. My project folder is structured as follows:

```
project /
    |-- OpenLayers.js
    |-- map.html
    |-- map.js
    \-- etc
```

As you can argue, when I start a new map project, I espect suggestions from Vim on how to complete the code, reading JS classes from all the libraries in the project folder (in this case, just `OpenLayers.js`).

E.g.:

```
map = new OpenLayers. --> <C-x><C-o>
map = new OpenLayers.Bounds
                    .Control
                    .Map
```

Selecting one of the suggested classes I should get a kind of autocompletion, like in Aptana. I've installed **AutoComplPop** and I get a nice automatic menu to select suggestions, but all of them are taken from the current JS file.

Anyway, I've correctly set up **Tagbar** + **node.js** + **jsctags** and I've generated `tags` file for my project, and added `set tags=./tags,./../tags,./*/tags` to my `.vimrc`.

In this case, also, Tagbar maps the current file JS structure but doesn't offer any mapping of the classes coming from other files.

Another probably relevant line in my `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd FileType javascript set omnifunc=javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS
```

I'm struggling to get class and subclass suggestions and now I'm getting a bit confused with all the plugins/piece of software available.

Any hint?
Thank you guys :)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Your expectations are a bit too high. Vim is not an IDE like Aptana and the mechanisms used to provide completion are crude.

Did you check that your `tags` file has `OpenLayers.Bounds`, `OpenLayers.Control` or `OpenLayer.Map`? I can't find `OpenLayer.Map` and, going through the `OpenLayer.debug.js` I can't find this function either.

TagBar only works with the current buffer. If you want to show tags for other windows/buffers you'll need another older plugin: TagList.

AutoComplPop doesn't support JS out of the box. How did you set it up? [Here is how I did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4779916/546861) but it still uses `<C-x><C-o>` while completion from `tags` is done with `<C-x><C-]>`.

Comment: Yeah, I've set up AutoComplPop as you suggested in the other post and now it works loading classes from `tags` file. The only embarrassing issue I'm getting now is related to Openlayers.js: `jsctags OpenLayers.js` gives me an embarassing `Error: fixStm: 44, line 261`, so I'm unable to create a `tags` file from it. But that's another story.

Comment: this answer might suggest giving up on setting the advanced autocomplete and definitions for Vim. There are plugins like youcompleteme and tern which seem to accomplish what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @MaciejJankowski, there was no YCM or Tern in 2012.

Comment: @romainl - could you please edit the answer so I can take the downvote off?

Comment: Hahaha… are you kidding?

Answer (score 5):

Check out [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) and [tern_for_vim](https://github.com/marijnh/tern_for_vim).

Here's an [article](http://tilvim.com/2013/08/21/js-autocomplete.html) about using them together.

Comment: this is the best autocomplete package I found. Thanks!