# How to configure vim for auto complete in Python file and Javascript file too

Tags: javascript, python, vim, vim-plugin, jedi

I work with vim for 2 years in cpp, and untill today, i used to auto complete my code with ctags. It wasnt great, but enough for my needs. 
Currently, i work with python and Javascript and i am looking for good tool which give me support for both languages.
I tried Jedi for python and i was great, but it has support only for python, so it cant help me for Javascript anf bash.

Any idea how can i configure my vim to support multiple languages?

My vimrc on: https://github.com/reubinoff/DotFiles/blob/master/.vimrc

Thanks

Comment: For javascript completion use [YouCompleteMe + tern_for_vim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22119945/7976758).

Comment: does it works with jedi and supertab? because after my jedi installation, it broke my context compilation

Comment: YouCompleteMe surely [works](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#python-semantic-completion) with jedi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks!
I tried [phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd) recommendation. [YouCompleteme + tern_for_vim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22119945/7976758) is really answer my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Although its highly opinionated I would highly recommend you checkout coc.nvim  (https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) which you can then use to install extensions for the languages you want to use, which then provide you with autocomplete and other features. A list of extensions for coc.nvim can be found here: https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/wiki/Using-coc-extensions#implemented-coc-extensions

Answer (score 0):

The plugin [deoplete](https://github.com/Shougo/deoplete.nvim) supports different languages via submodules. So also Javascript and Python etc.